# Regexp replacement character

Tags: regex, string, csv, go

I created a CSV file in Go and I have to add quotation marks(") in every column, I added these but this time, **CSV programming adds extra(double) quotation marks in *comment* column** (if there is the comma(,) in column)

My CSV

```
comment_ID","post_ID","product_SKU","comment_author","author_mail","author_location","date","comment"
"100","60574","VID17","Jordi","","","2021-06-02 16:20:30",""My son likes this video, good job""
"101","60574","VID18","Scarlett,"","","2020-12-29 23:06:32",""I don't like this video, it may be better""
```

I need CSV like this (there is not double quotation in comment columns"

```
comment_ID","post_ID","product_SKU","comment_author","author_mail","author_location","date","comment"
"100","60574","VID17","Jordi","","","2021-06-02 16:20:30","My son likes this video, good job"
"101","60574","VID18","Scarlett,"","","2020-12-29 23:06:32","I don't like this video, it may be better"
```

My Golang Code

```
RegContent := regexp.MustCompile(`",""[A-Za-z0-9]`)
newRegexp := RegContent.ReplaceAllString(CSV_Contents, `","`)
fmt.Println("PLAY: ", newRegexp)
err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, []byte(newRegexp), 0)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error: ", err)
}
```

Output

```
"son likes this video, good job" //(Missing My)
"don't like this video, it may be better" //(Missing I)
```

Comment: Both your current and your expected CSV files are invalid; the first column in the oeader line lacks the opening double quote.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiże, No, this also replaces "Scarlett,**""**,**""** => "Scarlett,**"**,**"** and "Jordi",**""**,**""** => "Jordi",**"**,**"**

Comment: @Axifive I see, the empty fields will be affected. So, the only question that remains is whether there are any `""` inside the comment column and how to treat them.

Comment: your CSV is als broekn at `,"Scarlett,""` It should contain a quote after Scarlett. How did you generate that CSV ? it is really bad; if possible, re gen your csv rather trying to fixing this. Unless you are just practicing. but then i should not help you much. I would just advise to stay away for regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get described behavior with [**ReplaceAllStringFunc()**](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc)

```golang
f := func(s string) string {
   return strings.ReplaceAll(s, `""`, `"`)
}
RegContent := regexp.MustCompile(`",""[^,].+""`)
newRegexp := RegContent.ReplaceAllStringFunc(CSV_Contents, f)
fmt.Println("PLAY: ", newRegexp)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1NqTyN1hs1J

And alternative with [**ReplaceAllString()**](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAllString):

```golang
RegContent := regexp.MustCompile(`,""([^,].+)""`)
newRegexp := RegContent.ReplaceAllString(CSV_Contents, `,"$1"`)
fmt.Println("PLAY: ", newRegexp)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tY8zGWTbLLB

Comment: alternative method (replaceAllString) worked directly!

Answer (score 2):

You can match the last column while capturing all between outer quotes and use a backreference in the replacement argument to `ReplaceAllString` to restore that part:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
        CSV_Contents := `
comment_ID","post_ID","product_SKU","comment_author","author_mail","author_location","date","comment"
"100","60574","VID17","Jordi","","","2021-06-02 16:20:30",""My son likes this video, good job""
"101","60574","VID18","Scarlett,"","","2020-12-29 23:06:32",""I don't like this video, it may be better""
`   
    RegContent := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m),"("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")"$`)
    result := RegContent.ReplaceAllString(CSV_Contents, `,$1`)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/XDPOF1BFoyE), output:

```golang
comment_ID","post_ID","product_SKU","comment_author","author_mail","author_location","date","comment"
"100","60574","VID17","Jordi","","","2021-06-02 16:20:30","My son likes this video, good job"
"101","60574","VID18","Scarlett,"","","2020-12-29 23:06:32","I don't like this video, it may be better"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sghZld/1). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on, `$` will match end of lines
- `,"` - a comma and `"`
- `("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")` - Group 1 (`$1`): a `"`, then any zero or more chars other than a `"`, then zero or more sequences of `""` (if there are escaped quotes inside comment column, they will be left intact) and then zero or more non-`"` chars, and then
- `"$` - a `"` at the end of a line.

Comment: it works on the terminal but if I run it on a CSV file, it doesn't work. I appreciate your efforts

Comment: @Melisa It means your contents are different from what you posted in the question. Probably, there are trailing spaces at the end of lines, and ``regexp.MustCompile(`(?m),"("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")"\s*$`)`` will work, but without the exact file, there is no guarantee.